# Is it possible to limit accessible fields when updating a row in ZF1?

Tags: zend-framework

In CakePHP (at least 3, not sure about 2), it's possible to set fields that are accessible when updating an entity or setting mass properties. This [at least helps to] prevent accidental (or malicious) settings of sensitive properties in objects that you don't want to set i.e. accidentally changing the ID, or role of a user, of an object when mass-setting properties (from a form, for instance).

I've looked around quite a lot and I can't find something similar to this in Zend Framework 1. Just before I roll my own `setFromArray()` method that takes the properties that are ALLOWED to be set, I'd like to check if anyone else has seen something similar in ZF1.